# How to print something without using std lib functions?

Tags: c

In the C language, when printing something on the screen, we usually use `printf`, `puts` and so on. Which are all defined in the  or other header documents.

Is there any way to print something on screen without using such functions? That is to say, how is `printf` realised?

Comment: I update my answer.sorry for wrong answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Printing to screen requires access to framebuffer (hardware) and userspace programs are not allowed to have a direct access to it. So what they do is make a system call and kernel performs the required function for them. `printf` -> `write` system call -> kernel writes the data into framebuffer and then control is given back to user program.
Even if you don't want to use `printf` or `puts` (they are implemented in hosted libc) still you have to use write system call to tell the kernel on which device you want to write the buffer.

Answer (score 11):

Eventually the C function `printf` will result in a `sys_write` system call, directly or by going through `write` (see `man 2 write`). The actual implementation depends on the compiler and the standard libraries.

Answer (score 1):

The standard headers are not, necessarily, a library containing functions written in C code.
They are functions with C "interfase", however it's very probably that they contain explicit machine code, adapted, in each case, to the target system.
The standard headers provide, in this way, ways of doing special process that it would not be possible to achieve in strict C code.

In the specific case of `printf()`, the situation is even more clear, because if none header is `#include-d`, then there is not any mechanism through the use of the C syntax only that performs an Input/Output operation.

Answer (score 0):

`library ncurses` can help you, but if you want to use a low level function use `write()` and if you want to do kernel programming you have to use `printk()`

Comment: The question has nothing to do with `bash` apart from `bash` being implemented in C. I rolled back the edit you made (adding the bash tag). If your answer is not applicable we can easily vote it down, but finding and correcting your inappropriate edits is much more effort, so please be more careful and conservative with your edits.